# need help! how to display uppercase string in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-16

this is the code, I'm realy confused right now

```
.model small    
.code    

org 100h        

begin: jmp a10main

coname db 'LAseR-12 SYstEMS XXX ','$'
            
a10main proc near

lea bx, coname+1     
mov cx, 15    
        
a20:    
mov ah, [bx]    
cmp ah, 41h    
jb a30    
cmp ah, 5ah    
ja a30    
xor ah, 00100000b    
mov [bx], ah            
a30:    
inc bx    
loop a20    
        
mov ah, 09h    
lea dx, coname    
int 21h

mov ax, 4c00h    
int 21h
       
a10main endp    
end begin
```

Comment: _"I'm realy confused right now"_. About what specifically?

Comment: Your program seems to display characters between `coname+1` and `coname+1+15` converted to lower case. You might be confused that it also converts other characters than 'A'..'Z', for instance the digit  '1' (ASCII 00110001b) gets converted by `xor ah,  00100000b` to ASCII 00010001b, which is a VerticalTabulator, the space (ASCII 00100000b) becomes NULL etc. Check the logic in boundery values `41h` and `5Ah`.

Comment: @vitsoft I don't see how the OP's code could mistakenly convert eg. '1' or ' '. It will exclusively change uppercase characters

Comment: @SepRoland You're right, the mistakenly conversion might happen if OP would have blindly applied `xor` on all characters, without checking boundery values (which he has wrong anyway).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Because of `lea bx, coname+1` and `mov cx, 15`, your program processes only part of the string at *coname*

```
LAseR-12 SYstEMS XXX $
 ^             ^
 A is first    S is last
```

Your loop is correct except that in order to obtain an uppercase string, you need to select the characters that currently are lowercase and change their case. The lowercase characters are in the range 61h to 7Ah. Either use those values or better use the according character constant like in the code below:

```
a20:
  mov  al, [bx]
  cmp  al, 'a'       ; 61h
  jb   a30
  cmp  al, 'z'       ; 7Ah
  ja   a30
  xor  al, 00100000b ; UCase
  mov  [bx], al
a30:    
  inc  bx
  loop a20
```

Tip: Use `AL` instead of `AH` and your code will get 3 bytes shorter.

---

Alternative: To convert the entire string, you can continu the loop until the terminating character **$** is found:

```
  lea  bx, coname-1
  jmp  a30
a20:
  cmp  al, 'a'       ; 61h
  jb   a30
  cmp  al, 'z'       ; 7Ah
  ja   a30
  xor  al, 00100000b ; UCase
  mov  [bx], al
a30:
  inc  bx    
  mov  al, [bx]
  cmp  al, '$'
  jne  a20
```